How to Search YouTube for Non-News Channels
Very often I'm trying to find a clip of some recent event but when I search YouTube, I get pages and pages of news reports (Fox, CNN, ABC, NBC, CBS etc), even though I know many users have posted the clip in pure and complete form, without all the talking heads "contextualizing" the clip for us.
I've tried using Google proper with a site:youtube.com filter, thinking if I don't select the News category it will be more apt to give me non-news, but that doesn't seem to work either—I get pages of news channel videos.
Is there something else I can try?
